# The web application not starting on tomcat when ehcache was upgraded from 1.5.0 to 2.8.3

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, ehcache

After upgraded the ehCache from version 1.5.0 to version 2.8.3 using Tomcat 7 the web application is not starting anymore and getting the following server logs error:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter SimplePageCachingFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimplePageCachingFilter
```

The SimplePageCachingFilter is used in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SimplePageCachingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimplePageCachingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

But could not found an alternative of SimplePageCachingFilter in ehCache 2.8.x

Would appreciate any idea to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SimplePageCachingFilter` was moved to the [`ehcache-web`](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/web-caching) module. You need to include it as a separate dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable hint, but the only thing is that not able to resolve (download) this dependency using maven. Any hint how to deal with this situation?

Comment: Do you have the version right? I think the last available one was 2.0.4

Comment: Yes have tried the last 2.0.4 version and also all available versions in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-web

Comment: This was because have added a maven dependency only for the parent pom.xml. When have added the dependency  also to the webapp (sub-module) pom.xml the dependency got resolved.